# Mongodb nested tree structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

How to fetch immediate child data in tree format??

Consider following sample data....If search key India then result should contain all the child node with project data...

**Project collection**

```
[ 
 { id : 1, name : "p1" location : Pune },
 { id : 2, name : "p2" location : Mumbai },
 { id : 3, name : "p3" location : Nashik },
 { id : 4, name : "p4" location : Pune },
 { id : 5, name : "p5" location : Maharashstra },
 { id : 6, name : "p6" location : Pune }
 ]
```

**Location collection**

```
 [
 {id : 1 name : 'l1' , 'location' : Pune , parentLocation : Maharashstra},
 {id : 2 name : 'l2' , 'location' : Nashik , parentLocation : Maharashstra},
 {id : 3 name : 'l3' , 'location' : Mumbai , parentLocation : Maharashstra},
 {id : 4 name : 'l4' , 'location' : Maharashstra , parentLocation : India},
 {id : 5 name : 'l5' , 'location' : India , parentLocation : null}

 ]
```

Expected result should be below....using mongo aggregation

I want retrieve all the project count with details....

**Expected Output**

```
 India - p1,p2,p3,p4,p5
    Maharashstra - p5
       Pune - p1,p4
       Mumbai - p2
       Nashik - p3
```

**Expected Json Output**

```
{
"location": "India",
"parentLocation": null,
"Child": [
    {
        "location": "Maharashstra",
        "parentLocation": "India",
        "ProjectCount": 6,
        "ProjectDetails" : [
            { "id" : 5, "name" : "p5", "location" : "Maharashstra"
            }
        ],
        "Child": [
            {
                "location": "Pune",
                "parentLocation": "Maharashstra",
                "ProjectCount": 3,
                "ProjectDetails": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "p1",
                        "location": "Pune"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "p4",
                        "location": "Pune"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "p6",
                        "location": "Pune"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "location": "Nashik",
                "parentLocation": "Maharashstra",
                "ProjectCount": 1,
                "ProjectDetails": [
                    {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "p3",
                    "location": "Nashik"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "location": "Mumbai",
                "parentLocation": "Maharashstra",
                "ProjectCount": 1,
                "ProjectDetails": [
                    {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "p2",
                    "location": "Mumbai"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Please refer above tree...for output
Thank you....

Comment: could you post your json output and some explanation to the question

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet ....I have uploaded Json output....can u please check

Comment: ok but how referencing will work in above output? which are the common keys in both the collections?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet , i want to retrieve all the project count of immediate child, with above tree structure

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet , the common filed is **location** in both collection

Comment: Just a tip Avinash you will not get your answer until you don't post your actual sample data and the output with pure clarification as I do... You can see my question for this

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes thank you for suggestion, i just need when i said **India** as search key then it just return all immediate child data with project details...if search key is Maharashtra then next immediate child of Maharashtra...